# plot function not displaying results of division of two vectors

Tags: matlab, plot, vectorization, matlab-figure

I  am attempting to plot percent overshoot as a function of the damping ratio.

The damping ratio range: 0 to 1

Here's what I have:

```
dr = (0:0.1:1);                    % Damping Ratio
PO = exp((-pi*dr)/sqrt(1 - (dr.^2))); % Percent Overshoot Function
plot(dr, PO)                          % Plot Function**
```

Here is what I get:
[image: Picture of generated plot with no lines. Correct Bounds.]

I know that the issue is with the square root component. When I remove the variable from the square root, the function plots. Not sure why.. please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For element-by-element vector arithmetic use `./`, `.*`, `.^` operators. The problem with your code is that you used `/`([right-matrix division](https://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/embedded.fi.mrdivide.html)) for division. Use `./` ([Right array division](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rdivide.html)) instead. [Here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/2292-matrix-division-how-does-it-work#answer_3553) is a description about what matrix division operators do.

Comment: @Maquen.z I'm glad it helped. You can [accept the post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), if it answers you question.